# Map Title base on displayed layer name

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.8

I have been trying to run code I found [Having title which includes dynamic text of layer name using ArcPy with ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129682) but I keep getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File "C:/Outputs/test.py", line 20, in <module>
>     TextElement = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT",'TitleText')[0]
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

The code I am using is below slightly modified from the original.

```
import arcpy, os

# Specify the map document and the data frame
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\Test_Map.mxd')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, 'Layers')[0]

#Output map directory
outPath = r'C:\Outputs'

#Iterate through layer names
LyrList = ['soilmu_a_ny053','soilsf_p_ny053']
for LyrName in LyrList:

    #Get current layer, make visible
    Layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, LyrName, df)[0]
    Layer.visible = True

    #Change title text
    TextElement = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT",'TitleText')[0]
    TextElement.text = LayerName

    #Get output JPG filename, remove existing, export
    Output_jpg = os.path.join(Output_dir,LayerName+".jpg")
    if os.path.exists(Output_jpg): os.remove(Output_jpg)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, Output_jpg, resolution=300, jpeg_quality=95)

    #Make layer invisible again
    Layer.visible = Fals
```

e

Comment: Check the name of your text element using its Properties dialog. I suspect it’s not TitleText in that exact case and without leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: I’ve checked that a few times. Doesn’t seem to change it. I have also renamed that completely to the same error. I have gotten index errors before but this one is a noodle scratcher

Comment: Have you tried '\*TitleText\*', the docs show that the wildcard is a combination or asterix (*) and characters. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayoutelements.htm